# Understanding duality in a lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

I'm just starting out looking at lattices, and I've hit a bump.  I'm using *Applied Abstract Algebra* by Lidl and Pilz. On p. 7, the authors define the duality principle:

> Any "formula" in a lattice $ ( L, \sqcap, \sqcup  ) $ involving the operations $ \sqcap $ and $ \sqcup $ remains valid if we replace $ \sqcap $ by $ \sqcup $ and $ \sqcup $ by $ \sqcap $ everywhere in the formula.

So far, so good. On p. 10, then, we see that

> [i]n every lattice $ L $ the operations $\sqcap $ and $\sqcup$ are isotone, i.e. $y\le z \implies x \sqcap y \le x \sqcap z$ and $x \sqcup y \le x \sqcup z$.

I *think* that the proof seems straightforward enough:

> $ y \le z \implies x \sqcap y = (x \sqcap x) \sqcap (y \sqcap z) = (x \sqcap y) \sqcap (x \sqcap z) $

— whence the first statement. (The last equality is obtained by applying associativity and commutativity, I assume?)

The authors then write

> The second formula is verified by duality.

But $y \le z$ does *not* imply that $ x \sqcup y = (x \sqcup x) \sqcup  (y \sqcup z)$; rather, we would need the LHS to be $x \sqcup z$.  I thought perhaps this was simply a matter of less-than-precise language (yes, I realize that's very unlikely), that perhaps I needed to make this simple change and then everything works out.  But there's nothing in the definition of the duality principle on p. 7 about making *other* "simple changes". What am I missing?

Comment: Small hint: when dualizing, $\le$ is replaced with $\ge$ and vice versa. This is because these relations are defined in terms of $\sqcup$ and $\sqcap$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Oh, right :). L&P write as much in the description of duality in a poset; so they give an interpretation of duality that uses ordering and an interpretation that uses binary operations. I hadn't realized one could use both at once, but it makes sense now. Thanks!